# “Simple past” vs “past progressive”

Tags: verbs, usage

Original conversation:

*“And you met her there?”
“Yes, I **spent** a lot of time in that library, so I was always seeing her.*”

Is it wrong to say

*“Yes, I **was spending** a lot of time in that library, so I was always seeing her.”*

Thank you in advance for your replies!